# AutoComplete Edittext while opening application

Tags: android

I made an android application in which there is login screen.The idea in this application is that,I got an email from my client on my gmail with link having credentials like this
    "http://www.xyz.com/a=3&b=u"
When I click on this link it open my application with login page and set these credentials automatically.I am able to open my app with login page but how to set these credentials in edittext automatically.So Is it possible to do so,Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Are you getting some Json response from server ? If it is then you need to use JSON parsing.

Comment: No it is just simple email having simple URL

Comment: So you can use `editText.setText("URL Here");`.

Answer (score 0):

In LogIn page of your application read the data from intent that opened this activity. As your manifest must be having intent-filter something like :

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data android:host="dummy host" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

so you will get the URL from data in intent. Then you can read the credentials a & b which you can set using `editText.setText()`